# uTorrent and bitTorrent on Android cannot download anything?

Tags: bittorrent

I tried to see how download is like on an Android phone, so I emailed myself a torrent file and then saved it in the Download folder.

And then I tried both uTorrent and bitTorrent app. But it only has "Open the torrent on http://____________", or there is a search function that leads the user to do searching on duckduckgo.com

There was no way to use a local torrent file in the Download folder.

So I tried setting up a webserver on my Mac and then use http://128.0.1.123/try.torrent (something like that) but it could not load it.  Duckduckgo.com led to some magnetic URL site, and I copied and pasted to uTorrent, and they cannot load either.

Is it possible to make it work?  I tried the LibreTorrent app and at least it can open a local torrent file and start downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution: go to the File Manager, and then open the torrent file, and choose "Open in app" and choose the app.

Why the app itself doesn't allow opening the file in itself, I am not sure.